# 405 error in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, routes

im sending a form data via ajax to the server using laravel 5.6
when sending the data to the server, i have specified the method of ajax to POST and the routing method in web.php to post too, the problem is,  ajax sendS the form data with GET method not POST. what should i change???

ajax code

```
var form = $('#personPersonalInfoForm')[0];
var formData = new FormData(form);

$.ajax({
    url:"/addNewPerson",
    Type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data)
    {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

web.php code

```
Route::post('/addNewPerson', 'adminController@addNewPerson');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

web.php

```
Route::post('/addNewPerson', 'adminController@addNewPerson')->name(admin.add_new_person);
```

in your adminController :

```
public function addNewPerson(Request $request){
   // you can check request parameters
   //return response()->json($request->all());

   // add new person code here ...

   return response()->json(array('status'=>'success','message'=>'person added'));
}
```

your ajax code should be :

```
$.ajax({
    url:"/addNewPerson",
    type: "POST",
    data:$('#personPersonalInfoForm').serialize(),
    dataType:'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data)
    {
        alert(data);
    }, 
    error:function(){
       alert('ERROR');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of working code using the FormData.
Using the **"method"** configuration instead of **"type"**.

```
var form = document.getElementById("ajaxForm");
var formData = new FormData(form);
var url = form.action;
$.ajax({
    method : 'POST',
    url : url,
    data : formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
}).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}).error(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

---

Dont forget to add the CSRF token in the form.

```
<form method="POST" action="/addNewPerson" id="ajaxForm">
    @csrf
    ...
</form>
```

**Or** configure the ajax method from the start with it.

in the **< head>** add

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and in the JavaScript add

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Comment: add the url in both form and ajax?

Comment: The url is only present in the form. it's better that way as you can use the same JS for multiple forms if you use the right event listener.
If you are talking about the CSRF token then No, you add it either in the form or the AjaxSetup.